# Highcharts - Indicator's data not showing in line chart

Tags: highcharts, indicator

1. I am fetching data from an endpoint
2. I display the data in a highchart
3. There are several indicators that can be selected. For each of them another yAxis is added below the main one.
4. My series data are of this format :

   ```
    series: [
     {
       data: [],
       id: 'prices',
       step: this.hasStep,
       name: this.$props.title,
       fillColor: 'rgba(127,183,240,0.2)',
     },
     {
       visible: false,
       type: 'column',
       id: 'volume',
       name: 'Volume_hardcoded',
       //linkedTo: 'prices',
       data: this.volumeSeries,
     },
   ],
   ```
5. I save the data in the following way (don't pay attention in the logic, it works fine):

   ```
      if (this.selectedTimeSpan.tickInterval === 1) {
       for (let i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
         let xData = null;
         this.selectedTimeSpan.getIntradayData
           ? (xData = Math.floor(new Date(prices[i].time).getTime()))
           : (xData = Math.floor(new Date(prices[i].date).getTime()));
         priceSeries[i] = {
           x: xData,
           open: prices[i].first,
           high: prices[i].high,
           low: prices[i].low,
           close: prices[i].last,
           y: prices[i].last,
           volume: prices[i].tradingVolume,
         };
         this.volumeSeries[i] = {
           x: xData,
           y: prices[i].tradingVolume,
         };
       }
     } else {
       let j = 0;
       for (
         let i = 4;
         i < prices.length;
         i += this.selectedTimeSpan.tickInterval
       ) {
         priceSeries[j] = {
           x: Math.floor(new Date(prices[i].date).getTime()),
           open: prices[i].first,
           high: prices[i].high,
           low: prices[i].low,
           close: prices[i].last,
           y: prices[i].last,
           volume: prices[i].tradingVolume,
         };
         this.volumeSeries[j] = {
           x: Math.floor(new Date(prices[i].date).getTime()),
           y: prices[i].tradingVolume,
         };
         j++;
       }
     }
   ```
6. When I select [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpREZ.png) indicators (they are based on the volume), I am getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVqeQ.png) result.(You can see a blank space below the main chart.) Instead when i swap to OHLC or candlestick my main series (series[0]) it looks works fine and it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5CvV.png). Any idea why is that happening? I haven't touched the tooltip settings at all (in case it was there a problem). I am struggling 2 days now with it can't really figure it out. Any help would be appreciated a lot. If you need more information feel free to comment so I can provide. Thanks in advance. Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, there's a flag that can be used called usedOhlcData in series object. (series[0] in my case]. We just set it to true.

```
series:[{
    data:[],
    useOhlcData:true,
    ...}
    ,{
    ...
    }]
```